# Dropping an assumption on bounded convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

If $f_n$'s are uniformly bounded complex valued functions converging pointwise to $f$ and $E$ is of finite measure, then we know that $f$ is integrable on $E$ and $\int_Ef_n\rightarrow \int_Ef$. How about we drop the assumption that $E$ is of finite measure provided that we a priori know $|\int_Ef|<\infty$?  Can we still say $\int_Ef_n\rightarrow \int_Ef$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Consider the line with Lebesgue measure.  The functions
$$f_n(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \frac 1n & |x| \le n \\ 0 & |x| > n \end{array} \right.$$ converge uniformly to $0$ yet satisfy $\displaystyle \int f_n = 2$ for all $n$.

Comment: Is there a general condition on $f_n$ which will make the conclusion in the question true?

Comment: Yes, look up the "dominated convergence theorem".